# AccessViolationException when logging onto a MAPI Profile

Tags: outlook, ms-office, mapi, outlook-2016

Part of our application is a windows process that logs onto MAPI and indexes email in the background. It works well with many different versions of Outlook, and up to a few days ago, used to work with Outlook 2016. Now it gives an AccessViolationException when logging on to a MAPI profile.

This is the exception message:

```
Exception thrown at 0x00007FFDA7716BB9 (Mso20win32client.dll) in Tray.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0000000000000000.
```

We haven't yet been able to figure out why it is trying to access that location. As far as we can tell, all arguments are valid.

The call stack looks like this (we don't have symbols for Outlook dlls):

```
 Mso20win32client.dll!00007ffda7716bb9()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda48e325e()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda48274e1()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda4827466()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda4827408()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda4827317()    Unknown
 CONTAB32.DLL!00007ffdee6a14f6()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda482670c()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda48261cd()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda48253c6()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda481653c()    Unknown
 OLMAPI32.DLL!00007ffda4815dc8()    Unknown
 MSMAPI32.DLL!00007ffdef225ee6()    Unknown
 [External Code]
```

There are some posts out there which talk about similar issues, one in particular which seems relevant is [this one on Experts Exchange](https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28967763/Outlook-constantly-crashing-and-restarting-faulting-module-mso20win32client-dll-Running-out-of-ideas.html), but we still haven't been able to identify the root cause or the fix.

Interestingly spikes (test programs) created to narrow down the issue do not exhibit the problem. Also MFCMAPI which is a tool for visualizing MAPI information works well, i.e. we are able to log on to the same profiles using it.

Has anyone else seen a similar issue? Any ideas on how to debug futher?

Answer (score 1):

You are loading olmapi32.dll. Do not do that - load msmapi32.dll.

Comment: Dmitry, our code is calling `MAPILogonEx` with the following flags: `MAPI_EXTENDED | MAPI_UNICODE | MAPI_EXPLICIT_PROFILE | MAPI_BG_SESSION | MAPI_NEW_SESSION`, and that is leading to the call stack described above, where the call does go through MSMAPI32.dll, and then to OLMAPI32.dll. What can we do differently? Also this used to work without any changes until a few days ago.

Comment: Also, we are using the MAPI Stub library approach, by having `MapiStubLibrary.cpp` and `StubUtils.cpp` in our project, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/cc963763.aspx

Comment: So is olmapi32.dll loaded by the call to MAPILogonEx or was it loaded before when you dynamically loaded msmapi32.dll and/or called MAPIInitialize?

Comment: It seems like `OLMAPI32.dll` is loaded as a result of the call to the `MAPIInitialize`.

Comment: Also, found [an article](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_officeinsider-mso_win10/outlook-build-16069652053-for-office-2016-causing/4ad99f17-fc9a-4b2c-acd9-0f3adcac5c52) that talks about the same issue. Subsequent to reading this article, we found that the issue repros when we call MAPILogonEx on a different thread than MAPIInitialize. On the surface, that seems to be the issue, but as I said in the question, this code worked for many months on many different versions of Outlook and only recently has started failing on Outlook 2016.

Comment: Do you actually do that? You need to call MAPIInitialize both on the main thread and on the secondary thread where you call MAPILogonEx .

Comment: Interestingly, all this time the code has been working even though we did not ensure that `MAPIInitialize` would be called on every thread that called `MAPILogonEx`. We did call `MAPIInitialize` with the `MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATION` flag and maybe that's why? And then an Office 2016 update caused it to break. Regardless, we are implementing the solution that ensures `MAPIInitialize` is called on every thread that will call `MAPILogonEx`. If you have any additional gotchas you know of, please let us know.

Comment: MAPI_MULTITHREAD_NOTIFICATION simply means you let MAPI to notify you on threads other than the primary one. MAPIInitialize must still be called on each thread.